# Query issue with two relations breaking tables or consolidating tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables and am having trouble even starting a query like the one below. Here is what I have tried but I am just now learning SQL.

**Attempt 1**

```
Select Employee.First_Name, Transactions.Transaction_Type, Transactions.Refund
From (Select Transaction_ID, Employee_ID, Transaction_Amount AS Refund, Transaction_Date, Reference_Transaction_ID
      From Employee INNER JOIN Transactions ON Employee.Employee_ID=Transactions.Employee_ID 
      Where Transaction_Type="Refund";) N,
      Employee INNER JOIN Transactions ON Employee.Employee_ID=Transactions.Employee_ID
WHERE Transaction_Type = "Sale";
```

**Attempt 2**

```
SELECT First_Name
FROM (
SELECT Employee.Employee_ID,Employee.First_Name, Transactions.Transaction_ID, Transactions.Transaction_Amount, Transactions.Transaction_Type, Transactions.Reference_Transaction_ID
FROM Employee INNER JOIN Transactions ON Employee.Employee_ID=Transactions.Employee_ID
    WHERE Transaction_Type = 'Sale'
UNION
SELECT Employee.Employee_ID,Employee.First_Name, Transactions.Transaction_ID, Transactions.Transaction_Amount, Transactions.Transaction_Type As Refund, Transactions.Reference_Transaction_ID
FROM Employee INNER JOIN Transactions ON Employee.Employee_ID=Transactions.Employee_ID
    WHERE Transaction_Type = 'Refund';
```

**Query in Question**
Provide the sales data along with net sales amount (sale – refund) for Sales agents with transactions occurring on or after 1/1/2017.  The output should include:

Employee Name, sales volume, refund volume, and net sales amount.

```
create table Employee
(Employee_ID int(45) primary key,
First_Name varchar(45),
Last_Name varchar(45),
Department_ID int(45),
Supervisor_ID int(45),
Salary int,
Hire_Date datetime,
End_Date datetime,
foreign key(Department_ID) references Department(Department_ID));

create table Transactions
(Transaction_ID int(45) primary key,
Employee_ID int(45),
Transaction_Amount float(45),
Transaction_Type varchar(45),
Transaction_Date datetime,
Reference_Transaction_ID int(45),
foreign key(Employee_ID) references Employee(Employee_ID));

INSERT INTO Employee
  ( Employee_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Department_ID, Supervisor_ID, Salary, Hire_Date, End_Date )
VALUES
  (1, 'Mary', 'Brown', 100, 7, 80000, 01/01/2014, 12/13/2015), 
  (2, 'John','Smail', 200, 3, 75000, 08/15/2013, null), 
  (3, 'Mike', 'Ray', 200, 10, 125000, 03/01/2016, null),
  (4, 'Steve', 'Ansky', 300, 5, 100000, 11/01/2013, null),
  (5, 'Jennifer','Ross', 300, 10, 130000, 04/03/2012, null), 
  (6, 'Jacob', 'Jones', 100, 7, 70000, 04/15/2011, null), 
  (7, 'Marisa','Sikes', 100, 10, 135000, 12/15/2014, null ),
  (8, 'Kate', 'OBrien', 200, 3, 70000, 02/12/2013, null),
  (9, 'Don', 'Chapman',300,5,80000,09/08/2011,06/13/2013), 
  (10, 'Lori','Reese',400, null, 250000, 06/01/2010, null);


INSERT INTO Transactions
  ( Transaction_ID, Employee_ID, Transaction_Amount, Transaction_Type, Transaction_Date, Reference_Transaction_ID )
VALUES
  (1, 2, 1125.24, 'Sale', 03/01/2017, null), 
  (2, 6,425.24, 'Refund', 03/03/2017, 1), 
  (3, 3, 123.21, 'Sale', 03/03/2017, null),
  (4, 3, 900.50, 'Sale', 03/04/2017, null),
  (5, 6,450.50, 'Refund', 03/06/2017, 4), 
  (6, 2, 823.43, 'Sale', 03/06/2017, null), 
  (7, 2,567.99, 'Sale', 03/07/2017, null ),
  (8, 8, 1003.21, 'Sale', 03/08/2017, null),
  (9, 8, 754.33, 'Sale', 03/08/2017, null), 
  (10, 7,553.21,'Refund', 03/10/2017, 8);
```

Comment: Can you post the create statements for your tables and/or the query you're working with please? That will help get you an answer faster. It's hard to create queries from images.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Hi. No pictures, thanks. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Normally, a query to return a resultset would start with the keyword `SELECT`. It would also include keyword `FROM` and the name of a table. If we have a query that we've attempted, even if its just a query that returns the names of the sales agents, that would show that we have done at least some work. (As the question stands right now, it looks like there hasn't been any work done.)

Comment: format the question so that it is readable. also,"having trouble" does not tell me what problem you are facing.

Comment: @Marty there is a lot of missing information.  Or at least confusing information.  You talk about Sales and Refund, but I don't see those in your tables.  How are they created?  Also, what SELECT statements have you tried?  What errors have those statements generated.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, this should work:

```
select E.Employee_name, 
  sum(case when T.Transaction_Type = 'Sale' then T.Transaction_Amount end) as Sales_Volume,
  sum(case when T.Transaction_Type = 'Refund' then T.Transaction_Amount end) as Refund_Volume,
  sum(case when T.Transaction_Type = 'Sale' then T.Transaction_Amount end) -
  sum(case when T.Transaction_Type = 'Refund' then T.Transaction_Amount end) as Net_Sales
  from Employee E
  inner join
  Transactions T
  on E.Employee_ID = T.Employee_ID
  where T.Transaction_Date >= '2017-01-01'
  group by E.Employee_name
```

It looks like you need to use the Reference_Transaction_Id from what I can tell, something like this:

```
With A as (
    select E.Employee_name, T.Transaction_ID, T.Reference_Transaction_Id,
      sum(case when T.Transaction_Type = 'Sale' then T.Transaction_Amount end) as Sales_Volume,
      sum(case when T.Transaction_Type = 'Sale' then T.Transaction_Amount end) -
      sum(case when T.Transaction_Type = 'Refund' then T.Transaction_Amount end) as Net_Sales
      from Employee E
      inner join
      Transactions T
      on E.Employee_ID = T.Employee_ID
      where T.Transaction_Date >= '2017-01-01'
      group by E.Employee_name, T.Transaction_ID, T.Reference_Transaction_Id
      ),
    B as (
    Select E.Employee_name, T.Transaction_ID, T.Reference_Transaction_Id,
      sum(case when T.Transaction_Type = 'Refund' then T.Transaction_Amount end) as Refund_Volume
      from Employee E
      inner join
      Transactions T
      on E.Employee_ID = T.Employee_ID
      where T.Transaction_Date >= '2017-01-01'
      group by E.Employee_name, T.Transaction_ID, T.Reference_Transaction_Id)

    Select A.Employee_name, A.Transaction_ID, A.Sales_Volume, A.Net_Sales, B.Refund_Volume
    from A left outer join B
    on A.Transaction_ID = B.Reference_Transaction_Id
```

Comment: Close, however the refunds reference the specific original order.